# Type orm Missing types

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am using typeorm to query data from the database. After getting the results, I map over them modifying a property. After returning the results i get this error.

```
is missing the following properties from type 'VesselMerged': hasId, save, remove, softRemove, and 2
```

This is VesselMerged entity

```
@ObjectType()
export class VesselMerged extends BaseVessel {
    @Field(() => Number, { nullable: true })
    sugarQuantity?: number;

    @Field(() => SugarType, { nullable: true })
    sugarType?: SugarType;

    @Field(() => String, { nullable: true })
    shipper?: string;

    @Field(() => VesselPort, { nullable: true, description: 'Loading port' })
    loadingPort?: VesselPort;

    @Field(() => KuleaVessel, { nullable: false })
    kuleaVessel: KuleaVessel;
}
```

It extends from BasseVessel Which is an entity.
I am mapping over each item modifying the key mmsi. If I return the results without mapping it works okay. The problem comes in when I modify the result.

```
 const searchBasedOnKey = ():Promise<VesselMerged[]> =>{
        const vesselMatches = await Vessel.find({
            where,
            relations: [
                'type',
                'navstat',
                'navstat.color',
                'kuleaVessel',
                'kuleaVessel.sugarType',
                'destinationPort',
                'destinationPort.country',
                'lastPort',
                'lastPort.country',
            ],
        });
      const d = vesselMatches.map(d=>({...d,mmsi:1}))
        return d;
    };

    }
```